# Mapping VM physical path to azure blob storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I would like to know if i can map physical path(C,D or E drives) of Virtual machine where my application is hosted, to Azure Blob storage.

Regards,
Vivek

Answer (score 1):

You cannot mount a blob container as a disk drive or do it the other way around. What you can do is storing VHDs as page blobs in a blob container.

If you're using Virtual Machines (IaaS), each persisted disk is stored as a page blob. You don't need to do anything for this (except for [adding a data disk](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/how-to-guides/attach-a-disk/) or using the system disk).

In your cloud services you can use the [Windows Azure Drive (X-Drive)](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2010/02/02/Using-Windows-Azure-Drive-%28aka-X-Drive%29.aspx), to mount a new drive letter which stores its data as a VHD in blob storage.

Note that in both cases, when you're looking at your blob storage with any tool like Cerebrata, Cloud Storage Studio, ... you'll see 1 single file (the VHD).

**Note:** You can revert to a custom solution like [FTP to Azure Blob Storage Bridge](http://ftp2azure.codeplex.com/)

Comment: One more detail: vhd's used in such a way have a single writer. They don't work as an SMB share. So, if you have 10 instances, you'd have to make snapshots for the other instances.

Comment: Basically what i want to achieve is..say i have to configure FTP server at IIS on Azure Virtual machine.WHile configuring the FTP,we need to specify the physical path(drive on vm) so that I/O operations are carried out smoothly using FTP client like Filezilla.Can i map Azure blob storage to the physical path at FTP.Hope i am clear with the question

Comment: If you use IIS this is only possible with a VHD stored in blob storage like I explained in my answer. If you really want to upload files directly to blob storage, and download files directly from blob storage through FTP you'll need something custom, like this: http://ftp2azure.codeplex.com/

Comment: Hi Sandrino,Thanks for your reply..                                   1. I would like to know what the difference between Virtual Machines   (IaaS) and Windows Azure Drive (X-Drive) on cloud services.       2.If i implemented custom ftp service on Azure worker role as mentioned at ftp2azure.codeplex.com ,how can i support SSL.

Comment: Read about the differences here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2012/06/28/data-series-exploring-windows-azure-drives-disks-and-images.aspx -) ftp2azure does not support SFTP, so you'll have to do something yourself

Comment: More over i created a cloud drive using following link http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2010/02/02/Using-Windows-Azure-Drive-%28aka-X-Drive%29.aspx...i was able to see the vhd created under page blob..can i see this on disk management of vm..i thought i will listed on VM hard disk as we have other drives like C,D etc..Please provide ur inputs